# not work remember_token in laravel how set remember_token and cookie?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, remember-me

I logged in through the Laravel authentication system and set Remember_token, After going from one link to another link (Route) The authentication system is down and I am Logout  ,
code for login and set remember_token :

Auth::login($user,true);

Answer (score -1):

Have used this

If you are "remembering" users, you may use the viaRemember method to determine if the user was authenticated using the "remember me" cookie

```
if (Auth::viaRemember()) {
    //
}
```

Ref
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#remembering-users

Answer (score -2):

Code for user registration:

```
 $user = new user;
$user->name = $request->user;
$user->email = $request->email;
$user->password = Hash::make($request->pw);
$user->tell = $request->tell;
if($request->hometel){$user->tel_sabet = $request->hometel;}
if($request->adress){$user->adress = $request->adress;}
$user->avatar = $filepath;
if($request->codepost){$user->codepost = $request->codepost;}
$user->remember_token = $request->token;
$id = $user->id;
$ok = $user->save();
if($ok){
    Auth::login($user,true);
   if($request->req !=""){
       return redirect('reqticher');
   }else {
    return redirect('/');
   }
```